# How to make sure two clients can't reach database at the same time (firebase real time database)?

Tags: database, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a simple multiplayer card game and I have two clients without server so I need an idea to give an id for each clients while they are running the same code. One idea is to have them choose one from the database, then deleting (/marking) it before the other can choose the same. Sadly I don't know how to make sure the database is unreachable for the other client between the time the first client gets the id and deletes it.

I use rest api for unity desktop. If you can just help me what to google, it would be very helpful (I'm very new to databases). Thank you!